# node js pass / send post data to html

Tags: node.js

Hello i'm new to node js and i am trying send / pass post data to html but i can't seem to get it to work And was hoping maybe someone could point me in the right direction on how i can.

Server code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/index.html");
});

app.post('/sendInfo', (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(`firstname: ${req.body.firstname} lastname: ${req.body.lastname}.`);
    var firstName = req.body.firstname,
      lastName = req.body.lastname;

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/info.html", { fistname: firstName, lastname: lastName });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("error", e);
  }
});

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

views/info.html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Site title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= fistname %></h1>
    <h1><%= lastname %></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Did you have a look at the `express` doc? Notably [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and [res.sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using the EJS template engine. So, there are a number of things that are missing in your code.

1. You need to tell express that you are using EJS at the template engine
2. The view must have an extension of `.ejs` not `.html`
3. You should be using `res.render()` and pass in the template name and the JSON data which will be used in the template

Set up a Node.js project using `npm init -y`, then run `npm install express ejs`, then create the `app.js` file (code given below) and finally create the `views/index.ejs` file (code given below). The `views` directory should be at the same level as your `node_modules` directory.

```
// app.js

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3006;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));

app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/fn/:first_name/ln/:last_name', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        first_name: req.params.first_name,
        last_name: req.params.last_name
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => { 
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`); 
});
```

---

```
// views/index.ejs

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>First name is <%= first_name %></div>
    <div>Last name is <%= last_name %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your `package.json` file must look something like this, use the `start` script

```
{
  "name": "node-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Run the app using `npm start`

Finally, open up a browser and hit `http://localhost:3006/fn/John/ln/Doe`

If all goes well you will see an html rendered in the browser like this...

```
First name is John
Last name is Doe
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Good luck.

Note: For the sake of simplicity I used `GET` instead of `POST` and used path params instead of request body. But the template engine works the same way.